In my sympy piecewise expression how do i specify the value of what x is everytime in my function?
I'm coding in python and I have a sympy summation that is almost complete with the formula that I want to use. I want to add the current value of x to the c value in my function so that it will print a different value everytime and give me the correct data.
Below is the code I'm currently dealing with:
def formula(address):

    address0 = int(address,16)

    def formula109(b,c):

       f = (b + c) - b

       formula10 =hex(int(f))

       d = (int(formula10,16) - b) + b

       return d


    expr = Piecewise(
        (formula109(x,0+0), Eq(x,0)),  #When x equal any value take that value and add it to formula109
        
        (formula109(x,0+0), Eq(formula109(x,0+0) ,address0)),
        (0, True)  # For all other values of logic, return 0
    )

    total = summation(expr, (x, 0, 92839293283922032923))
    terms = [expr.subs(x, k) for k in range(1, 5)]
    print(terms)
    print(total)

As you can see in the expr variable for the piecewise function I'm trying to add 0 to the c value of formula109() which is just a placeholder. I want to add the current value of x in all the numbers of the summation to the 0 so that I can print a different result in the formula109() function each time. The 0 in Eq(x,0) is a placeholder too because I don't know what to specify for 0.
Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I want to change the 0 + 0 to be 0 + whatever the current value of x is at the time of the summation's algorithm to solve the formula.
I'm not looking for any loops such as for loops or while loops to do this because I need everything instantly.

The same question from your last post applies here: what is the point of b in formula109? It does nothing there. And not just that, you convert f (which is really just c) to hex and then convert it back to base 10. In the end, formula109 can just be return c, since that's all it does.

"I'm not looking for any loops such as for loops or while loops to do this because I need everything instantly." Assuming your summation was over some complicated function, you cannot void having loops. You can only avoid a loop for a summation when there exists an analytical result.

@jared the b in formula109 is used because I need sympy to recognize this as a formula so in my pieceewise function it will directly pull the result of what is causing the number I'm trying to reach.
I converted f to hex and back to base10 for example purposes because my real code is complex and I need to see how to properly do it from this example.

@jared You can void having loops I've tested sympy and it is all instant sir.

If b doesn't do anything then don't even bother using it in the function. And sympy is not instant. As I said, there is no way to do a summation of a complicated function without a loop.

Since formula109 always returns c and in expr, c is 0 then expr is just 0: 0 when x is 0, 0 when address0 is 0 and everywhere else 0. So total = 0 and terms = [0,0,0,0]. If you don't want this, you have to pass something other than 0+0 as c to formula109.
